# Не загружается картинка с портом в twitter через Open Graph

Tags: html, html5, seo, twitter, opengraph

Одинаковые настройки. Если указывать картинку без порта, то работает. А если указывать с портом, то не работает.

Вот эти картинки не грузятся:

https://webro.ml:8083/images/sprite.png?1446554103
https://www.findmyprofession.com:8443/uploads/5b9be7d31857d.jpg

А вот эта грузится https://www.findmyprofession.com/assets/images/job-opportunities/google.jpg

Проверяю здесь http://seo-test.webro.ml/index23.html

А вот ссылка на твиттер https://twitter.com/alexanderMyrav1

В [документации](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started.html) было написано добавить **robots.txt**, не помогло.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta
        name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
    >
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@nytimesbits"/>
    <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@nickbilton"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/12/08/a-twitter-for-my-sister/"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="index23 A Twitter for My Sister kepa"/>
    <meta
        property="og:description"
        content="index23 the early days, Twitter grew so quickly that it was almost impossible to add new features because engineers spent their time trying to keep the rocket ship from stalling."
    />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.findmyprofession.com:8443/uploads/5b9be7d31857d.jpg"/>
    <meta
        property="og:image:secure_url"
        content="https://www.findmyprofession.com:8443/uploads/5b9be7d31857d.jpg"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi index23</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**robots.txt**

```
User-agent: Twitterbot
Disallow:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Твиттер отказывается загружать картинки с портом?

Как можно обойти это?

В валидатор вставлял с портом и без. Говорит ошибок нет.

Comment: Заходили на https://webro.ml:8083/images/sprite.png?1446554103 ? там же не валидный SSL сертификат! правильно что не грузят

Comment: Но все равно у второй картинки валидный сертификат и не грузит. Например https://www.findmyprofession.com:8443/uploads/5b9be7d31857d.jpg

Comment: По логам вебсервера сюда твиттер ходит? https://www.findmyprofession.com:8443/robots.txt и когда был последний раз? Ну и вообще по логам - он на картинку с портом он не ходит?

Comment: [Мана по траблшутингу](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/troubleshooting-cards). А про порт - там написано `Run your web server on a different, publicly-accessible port`, то есть нет явного указания на 80/443

Comment: https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Comment: Как вариант залить на другой хостинг и использовать оттуда.
https://pp.userapi.com/c850424/v850424961/bae5e/92G90VJ7tno.jpg
https://pp.userapi.com/c850424/v850424961/bae66/w_IK0A0NUss.jpg

Comment: А главное на facebook и на других социальных сетях работает с портом.